# Can FragmentResultListener used with the same request key in multiple fragments?

Tags: android-fragments, fragment, fragmentmanager

I have FragmentA(nav_graph_a), which navigates to FragmentB(nav_graph_b).
FragmentB navigates to a DialogFragment, which call setFragmentResult(RK_SHARED).
**Both** FragmentA and FragmentB registers a FragmentResultListener with request key **RK_SHARED**.

The problem is that in this case, the fragmentResultListener callback is not triggered in FragmentB.

Question: can I reuse the same request key to register FragmentResultListener in multiple fragments.
I could obviously solve this by using a unique request key. But what are the best practices?

Answer (score 0):

What method you used to set the fragment result listener? Maybe it is using a different `FragmentManager` and this is the reason why it doesn't receive the result.

Also, not sure if you want to receive the result in both fragments or not. But the `FragmentResult` **API** does not support that. Basically, only the last one that registered a listener with that key will be used because the `FragmentManager` relies on a map to set the results `Map<String, Bundle>` which does not allow for duplicate keys.